# Как посчитать поля в произвольных типах записи WordPress?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, acf, elementor

На WP сайте есть произвольный тип записи "Мастера", у этого типа записи есть произвольное поле "Отзывы". Как мне посчитать отзывы мастера и вывести это число на его странице?

Comment: произвольное поле "Отзывы" -- что за произвольное поле? Репитер?

Comment: @Simon, да, я нашёл, где они хранятся в БД, где "10" - это количество отзывов. Знаете как вывести это значение на страницу мастера? Вот, посмотрите: https://disk.yandex.kz/i/YfarZUksv7qdYw

Comment: `get_field()` репитер поля вернет массив, потому просто сделайте `get_field()` репитера и используйте [count()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.count.php)

Comment: @Simon, спасибо, сейчас попробую

Comment: @Simon, не сочтите за наглость, не могли бы показать пример использования и вывода?

Comment: `$number = count(get_field('repeater_field_name'));`

Comment: @Simon, get_field - это функция ACF. ТС не говорил что у его ACF (более того, я точно знаю что **не** ACF - см https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1460544/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%be-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b5%d0%b9-%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b3%d0%b0-%d1%83-%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8f)

Comment: @SeVlad тоже сомневался на счет ACF, но увидел в метках, потому предположил что все же ACF, по другому вопросу становится ясно что не все же ACF, спасибо. Ну на самом деле если знать мета ключ, то можно использовать `get_post_meta()` вместо `get_field()`. JetEngine не пользовался, возможно там есть более релевантные функции.

Comment: @Simon, да, я ошибся, выводя "ACF" в метки. Сейчас дошел до использования get_post_meta.
У меня такой код:
<?php

$seo_description = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'otzyvy-reap_copy', true );
 
if( $seo_description ) {
  echo '<meta name="description" value="' . esc_attr( $seo_description ) . '" />';
}

?>

Но ничего не выходит. Где я накосячил?

Comment: А что возвращает `$seo_description`?